# ThriftSecurityException (user:root, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)

Tags: java, accumulo

When I try to connect to accumulo from a java client, it is failing.  I am using the 'root' user but have changed the password.  I debugged my code, it is in fact getting the correct user name and password, the same I one I use to log into the shell with.

I read on some other sites that I have to set 'trace.user' and 'trace.password' in my accumulo-site.xml file, so I did that and restarted accumulo.  Unfortunately it did not change a thing.

When I try to connect from java, these are the important lines from the stack:

```
Caused by: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloSecurityException: Error BAD_CREDENTIALS for user root - Username or Password is Invalid
Caused by: ThriftSecurityException(user:root, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)
```

From my accumulo console, I see this:

```
08 15:44:06,0544    tserver:michael-GA-890GPA-UD3H  4   
ERROR
ThriftSecurityException(user:root, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)
```

When I look through my accumulo logs I just see the same exception and its stack getting printed every second that goes by.

I went looking through the accumulo manual and couldn't find anything that I'm missing.  A google search and SO search also did not help me.

Would somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: in case anybody else has this issue, I found a way to work around it.  I just created a new user in my accumulo shell, with minimal permissions, and I use that for my connections.  I would still appreciate an answer to this question though, since the error messages keep building up in my logs.

Comment: I also had to do "setauths -s public -u <user>" to give the new user the appropriate authorizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version you're using, you may also have trace.token.property.password defined in accumulo-site.xml which is the replacement for trace.password. >=1.6.0 introduced the trace.token.property.password property. If both that property and trace.password are present in the configuration, trace.token.property.password will take precedence over trace.password.

Look at the $ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR/tracer_$hostname.debug.log file, you'll likely have numerous exceptions in there.

The "proper" way (read as: how you'd want to do it in a production environment) to configure the tracer is to create the 'trace' table as 'root', create a 'trace' user, and give the 'trace' user READ, WRITE and ALTER_TABLE permissions on the 'trace' table. Then, update trace.user and trace.token.property.password in accumulo-site.xml.

Comment: thanks, I should have mentioned in my original post that I also changed the trace.token.property.password to have the correct password.  I also just gave root the 'public' authorizations.  The exception is still building up once a second in my logs.  Could it be due to the special characters in my password?  I have # and ! in my password.

Comment: The authorizations shouldn't matter, nor should any special characters in the password.

Comment: After a lot of experimentation, I believe that the exclamation mark in my password was the culprit.  I changed my password to a simple one, updated the site file, and it worked.  I tried changing it back but it would not let me create a password with an exclamation mark in it, accumulo produces an exception saying the event was not found.  When you initially create the root user though, you can get away with an exclamation mark in your password, which is how I got in that situation.  Your recommendation to create the separate user with appropriate permissions also worked for me.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in JLine (The "event not found" msg). I'll open an issue so we can try to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still want the solution or not, what helped me is changing the value of `trace.token.property.password` to the correct password, i.e., the value of `instance.secret` for the `trace.user` 'root' in `accumulo-site.xml` file.

Or you could open the acccumulo shell using the 'root' user and create a new user inside the shell and then update the values of both the trace user and it's current password.